# Identicon changes unexpectedly

Tags: support

Here's the problem (don't know if it really is, not sure if it's a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)).

I recently noticed that my identicon avatar changes frequently, although I haven't changed the email address / Google account since signing up to StackOverflow ~2 years ago.

The "My Logins" page contains only one Google account:

[image]

Others seem to notice that too (these are from one of the SO chat rooms):

- @*< my name >* how many email addresses do you have?!
- Err! You change your gravatar daily?
- Do you have a new avatar?
- Hmm, *< my name >*'s avatar just spontaneously changed color.

I joined about 10 SE sites recently (with the same old email address / Google account), could this have affected the identicon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your OpenID logins do not provide the email address that is used for your Gravatar, no. If your Gravatar keeps changing, it'll be based on your IP address instead, because you didn't attach an email address to your profile directly.

Click on *edit* in your profile and set an email address *there*:

[image: email edit field in profile]